# VSCode building flutter app on web but fails on mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

For some reason VSCODE is fine building on web browsers but displays errors when building on mobile,
here's the error log:

`

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\Juam Pablo\OneDrive\20_MISION TIC\CICLO 4\RETOS\RETO 03\reto3\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2bb0edd74be3f4e033f71b55b6fd8975\kernel_snapshot.d
: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
lib/interfaz/chat.dart:1
import 'dart:html';
       ^

Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=
StandardFileSystem 
only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
<asynchronous suspension>

#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:625:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1451:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (

fi
le:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
4

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

`

I tried fixing my yaml file but it didn't worked, i imported the HTML library it mentions although I haven't imported it in any file.

Answer (score 0):

check `lib/interfaz/chat.dart` if it has the import `import 'dart:html';`. if yes try removing it as it might be added by mistake from vscode and that's why it's not compiling.